# Why do I get this error 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string'?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried to create a scalar function that takes date and returns month name of that date

The code is

```
create function getmonth
    (@date date)
returns varchar(20)
begin
    declare @month varchar(20)
    set @month = format(month('@date'),'mmmm')

    return @month
end
```

When I tried to run it with code

```
select dbo.getmonth('3.1.2023')
```

I get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

How can I solve that?

Comment: The format should be `'MMMM'` (upper case). Also use the `'YYYYMMDD'` format to specify date literals. Because it is not clear whether '3.1.2023' is supposed to be '2023-03-01` or '2023-01-03`. You could get a surprise when running this code on another machine.

Comment: `month('@date')` -> `month(@date)` (you don't need string delimiters around a string parameter). But also that's a really bad format, I don't even know if that's March 1 or January 3, so SQL Server is going to have to guess too (based on `@@language`, `@@dateformat`, and regional settings). Finally, [format is awful](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but). Why not `DATENAME()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting an error message because your syntax is incorrect. Your function is attempting to call:

```
month('@date')
```

Which is similar to trying to call:

```
month('put any old string here, still not a param')
```

You need to have:

```
MONTH(@date)
```

Combining with other issues:

- I wouldn't use a function for this at all, but if I did, it would be an inline table-valued function, not a scalar one.
- `FORMAT` is [extremely expensive](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but). You can do the same with `DATENAME()` and not invoke the wrath of the CLR.
- The format `3.1.2023` is ambiguous and confusing. Why wouldn't you use a format that does not rely on `@@language`, `@@dateformat`, and regional settings to interpret correctly? `yyyyMMdd` is about 8 billion times better.

Without a function, and assuming you can't fix the format, and assuming that's `dd.MM.yyyy` (I'm still guessing), you can use `CONVERT()` with style 104:

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, TRY_CONVERT(date, '3.1.2023', 104));
```

If it's `MM.dd.yyyy`, use 110 instead (which is the closest match).

As a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.getmonth
(
  @DateString varchar(20)
)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
  RETURN 
  (
    SELECT MonthName = DATENAME(MONTH, 
     TRY_CONVERT(date, @datestring, 104)) -- or 110
  );
```

Then you can say:

```
SELECT MonthName FROM dbo.getmonth('3.1.2023');
```

Or:

```
SELECT d.name, d.create_date, f.MonthName
  FROM sys.databases AS d
  CROSS APPLY dbo.getmonth
    (CONVERT(char(10), d.create_date, 104)) AS f;
```

- [Example db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Y8bLngOu)